# Laravel relationships not working in some cases

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I'm working with Laravel `9.52.5` and have a problem with relationship loading

There are two tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE `creatives` (
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `creative_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `creatives_creative_name_index` (`creative_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `creative_items` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creative_uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `creative_items_sort_order_index` (`sort_order`),
  KEY `creative_items_creative_uuid_foreign` (`creative_uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `creative_items_creative_uuid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`creative_uuid`) REFERENCES `creatives` (`uuid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1272 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and 2 models

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquence\Behaviours\CamelCasing;
use Eloquence\Behaviours\Uuid;
use Eloquence\Database\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Creative extends Model
{
    use Uuid;
    use CamelCasing;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'creative_name',
    ];

    public function creativeItems(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CreativeItem::class)->orderBy('sort_order');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquence\Behaviours\CamelCasing;
use Eloquence\Behaviours\Uuid;
use Eloquence\Database\Model;

class CreativeItem extends Model
{
    use Uuid;
    use CamelCasing;

    protected $fillable = [
        'creative_uuid',
    ];
}
```

As soon as I'm trying to load `Creative` with relation `creativeItems` as a result
`creativeItems` collection is empty

```php
$creative = Creative::query()->whereCm360Id($cm360Id)->with('creativeItems')->first()
```

But when trying to make

```php
$creative = Creative::query()->whereCm360Id($cm360Id)->first();
$creativeItems = $creative->creativeItems()->get();
```

It works perfectly and returns not empty collection.

I have made small tests and detect as soon as `uuid` starts with digit `1-9` it doesn't work, if `0` or any letter works perfectly.

P.S. I know, I can left working variant but I would like to know hot to solve a problem with my original code.

Comment: You'll need to [override the relationship key in the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), since it's not in the expected `creative_id` column

Comment: @aynber I tried. Doesn't help. If it was a problem. Lazy loading will not work too...

Comment: You may also need to add `protected $keyType = 'string';` to your Creative model, since your id is not an integer